# 'undefined reference' problem of using FFTW

Tags: c++, c

I am a beginner of the great FFT library "FFTW", and nowdays I've met a strange problem which confused me:

I've downloaded the pre-compiled binary packet for Windows, and I've written some test codes which include the function like 'fftwf_malloc' etc, but when I tried to compile the codes, I just got 'undefined reference' problems :(

I've searched the header codes and I've found that the header file 'fftw3.h' seems doesn't define the 'fftwf_malloc' at all ... Then how can use it ? I am just confused ...

Dose anyone knows something about this ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to tell your compiler/linker where to find the appropriate library.  On Unix system, link with `-lfftw3 -lm`.  On Windows, the way to do this is probably going to depend on what compiler you're using.

Comment: This is really a basic issue of compile&link, I've figured it out, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: FFTW comes built in various precisions, so you may need to do `-lfftw3 -lfftw3f`. If you skip one of those the undefined-symbol errors don't change much so it's easy to overlook.